# "Developed by" vs "Developed at"

Tags: meaning, differences, prepositions

Normally I see things written this way :

> Developed **by** Joe Doe

But I have also seen instances where it says:

> Developed **by** Company Inc.

Now, I know it doesn't make sense to say:

> Developed **at** Joe Doe

But I have sometimes seen it say:

> Developed **at** Company Inc.

What's the difference between saying something was *developed 
**by** a place* versus saying that something was *developed **at** a place*?

Is there even any difference between those?

My initial assumption was that maybe someone who isn't part of Company Inc. used their facilities and did their development there, but now I'm not sure.

Comment: The distinction would be identifying the individual vs the company, it's purely personal preference when using 'by' or 'at' when referring to the company.

Comment: *by* for "developed by a person"; either for "developed at/by a company"; *at* for "developed at a location".

Comment: You may find you can get a more detailed answer/explanation at our sister site [ell.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say *developed by* someone, it means that the product or thing was developed by that *someone*- the developer of the product. When you say *developed by ABC, inc.* it means that the product or thing was developed by ABC's staff- the employees collectively working on the product.

When you say, *developed at ABC, inc.* it means that the product was developed at ABC, indicating a location of the company in question.

In most cases it would roughly give the same meaning, as most products are developed both by a company and at a company. However, it's possible that the product is developed or designed by a company but assembled at a different place and by different people. For example:

> The iPhone was designed by Apple in California, but it was assembled by a different company in China.